# Adding derived UserControls to List<> in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-controls

Im trying to create a list of wpf user controls and then set the mainwindows content to the usercontrol at runtime.

Since all UserControls will also share interfaces I want to build them from a derived window class as such:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl, IControlState
    public string ControlName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetType().Name;
        }
    }

    public void UseState(object parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Class derived from UserControl

```
public partial class Buglist : UserControl
{
    public Buglist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Class derived from my BaseControl

```
public partial class Login : BaseControl
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The Login xaml to allow Visual Studio designer to recognize a designable component

```
<MyType:BaseControl x:Class="BugAnalyzer.Controls.Login"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BugAnalyzer.Controls"
         xmlns:MyType="clr-namespace:BugAnalyzer.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="login" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

In my main window I want to be able to add these controls to a list and then be able to access shared properties such as ControlName.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<UserControl> uclist = new List<UserControl>();
    List<BaseControl> bcList = new List<BaseControl>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Buglist UserControlDerivedWindow = new Buglist();
        Login BaseControlDerivedWindow  = new Login();

        uclist.Add(UserControlDerivedWindow); //Works
        bcList.Add(BaseControlDerivedWindow); //Fails

     }
```

why can I add the class derived from UserControl to a list UserControls 
but not a class derived from BaseControl to a list of BaseControls?

Comment: What's the error message/exception that's "failing"?

Comment: Don't do this. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: @Clemens I think you're missing what he's asking... He's wanting to do full windows with major differences, not just different data with similar/same template.

Comment: Oppassum, Thats correct. Each Window \ user control will work with \ display completely different data, though some Window \ User Controls will rely on data retrived by another Window\ Control

Comment: Still didn't tell me what "failing" means.

Comment: I've done this with just based classes, not UserControls, and it works just fine.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, it's clear that "fails" doesn't refer to simply adding the object to the list; the types are, according to what you posted, compatible and you can in fact add the `Login` object referenced by `BaseControlDerivedWindow` to the `bcList` object, which has the type `List<BaseControl>`. So you must mean something else, but you haven't explained what that something else is. Please improve your question so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: @oppassum: I don't think Clemens is missing anything at all. Building collections of UI elements in code-behind is pretty much _always_ the wrong approach in WPF, and pretty much _always_ should be done by using collections of view model objects which are automatically mapped to appropriate UI elements via templates. There's very little context in this question, making it hard to understand, but there's certainly nothing here that suggests that templating isn't going to work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I have solved this though I not sure what the root issue was

For clarity in the question I wrote

```
 Login BaseControlDerivedWindow  = new Login();
```

but the actual code was

```
Login login = new Login();
```

which caused the compiler to issue something like "
Cannot covert from Program.Controls.Login to Program.Controls.BaseControl"

after I changed the code for clarity it compiled and then let me rename the Login instance back to login and compiled no issues again.